# Detect in Cmake if FindLAPACK finds OpenBLAS

Tags: cmake, lapack, openblas

I'm using old Cmake version(3.1) which detects OpenBLAS as Generic version in FindLAPACK.cmake

Now I can find if openBLAS is installed or not but how to detect if LAPACK returned by FindLAPACK is the OpenBLAS version.

Using regex won't work either because the LAPACK_LIBRARIES gives path such as

`/usr/lib/liblapack.so` but internally it points to

`/usr/lib/openblas-base/liblapack.so.3`

Is there any other way such as searching for a function or something else?

Comment: You can distribute recent `FindLAPACK.cmake` along with your source.

Comment: Indeed, in the recent version of `FindLAPACK.cmake`, the variable `BLA_VENDOR` can be set to  `OpenBLAS` to only check that vendor. https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmakeThen, you can try to set `BLA_VENDOR` to `OpenBLAS`, then `find_package()` lapack, then test `LAPACK_FOUND`. If false, unset `BLA_VENDOR` and call `find_package()`, lapack, REQUIRED.